# How to fix layout changes from bootstrap upgrade from 3 to 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nuget

Security made me upgrade jQuery from 3.2.1 to 3.6.0 and bootstrap from 3.3.7 to 5.0.1 using NuGet, and to get rid of old hand-installed jQuery/bootstrap files, and now I am having some layout problems that I cannot fix.

**Symptom 1**

Here I got a visible button "Toggle navigation". Before, this button was invisible. The info I found on css class `sr-only` said that it should make invisible on a screen reader (reading screen content to a blind computer user), but I don't have a screen reader but a firefox/chrome browser. I would guess this class should show for Screen Reader Only. In any case, this button does nothing so I commented it out.

```
<nav>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <!-- button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" 
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button -->
                <a href="/" class="pull-left">
                    <img src="/Images/company_logo.png" />
                </a>
                <span id="span_pagetitle" class="pull-left span_pagetitle" runat="server">
                   Page Title
                </span>
            </div>
```

Strange still that the Chrome dev tools, under Elements, Styles, show that `sr-only` was handled by bootstrap.min.css,  but with the new Bootstrap5 by _reboot.scss . The underscore suggests that this is a temp file, and the extension that it has to do with the higher level CSS system SCSS or SASS

In the DevTools, under Network, I still see that bootstrap.min.css was downloaded from the Content folder.

**Symptom 2**

In the above header code, the logo image and page title showed nicely on the same height in a light grey header bar. But after the upgrade, the layout is gone, ruined. Image and text have lowered, but with different amounts, and there is no light grey header bar as background for the image and text.

*Do I need to learn SASS to fix this problem?*

*Or did something possibly go wrong with installing bootstrap?*

To be honest, I had to manually copy the jQuery files from packages to Scripts.
I am now also wondering about jquery-ui.min.js/css and jquery-latest.min.js from a not upgraded version from package mutty-keyboard, as shown by the Network tab of DevTools. Could that cause interference with bootstrap???

Thanks for any hint that may possibly nudge me in the right direction.

---

Update:

While the answer on this question is actually very useful, I also found out that there is no such thing as an upgrade from Bootstrap 3 to 5. Those are just different toolkits. So this question is in a way obsolete. The real answer should be, don't upgrade. Use Bootstrap 5 on your new project.

The security scan that suggested this upgrade is doing too many upgrade suggestions, perhaps to get you scared and take your wallet out :-)

Comment: hi Roland.
did you find any solution to fix this issue because my website breaks too after switching to newer versions of BS, such as versions 4 or 5. i saw your update too.
does it mean that there is no way to upgrade from bootstrap 3 to 5 without any massive change in the layout of our website?

Comment: @Matin The bottom line is that bootstrap 5 is NOT the upgrade of bootstrap 3 or 4. These are in fact different projects. If you selected Bootstrap 3 or 4, just keep using this and do not try to "upgrade" to 5. Going to a higher Bootstrap number is more like a conversion project and is certainly not trivial. Better consider Bootstrap 5 for your next project or web page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, many things have changed in the newer version of the bootstrap. First, you don't need to learn SASS for this, this is only gameplay of class names that have changed in the newer versions.

For example, you have highlighted the `sr-only` class but in the newer version, the name of this class has changed.

> Renamed .sr-only and .sr-only-focusable to .visually-hidden and .visually-hidden-focusable

The only thing you have to do is go through this documentation and your all problems will be solved.

**Also, in the newer version, there is no need for jQuery.**

Read all about Bootstrap version migrations in these document - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/

Comment: so basically there is no way to migrate smoothly but to change/modify all changed classes...
...because I have similar issues. I just didn't check the file initially for used version